# Show that if $M\subset{\mathbb R}$ then there cannot be both a right-most point of $M$ and a first point to the right of M.

Tags: analysis

I am needing to prove this in a math analysis order.

So far I have gathered,
If $M$ is not bounded above, then it can't have a right-most point or a first point to the right of it. So we can assume $M$ is bounded above. Since the Reals are complete, $M$ has a least upper bound $P$. If $P$ is in $M$, then $M$ has a right most point, and $(P,\infty)$ has no first point. If $P$ is not in $M$, then there is a sequence of strictly monotonic increasing points in $M$ converging to $P$, and $M$ has no right-most point.

I am a little confused on putting this in a more traditional manner and not quite sure if I have all of my "facts" straight.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you say is true, but not everything is stringent. How do you know that $P\in M$ implies that $(P,\infty)$ has no first point? If $P\notin M$, how do you know that $P$ is the first point "to the right of $M$"?

Instead argue as follows: Assume that there are a rightmost point $a\in M$ and a first point $b$ "to the right of $M$". This implies $a<b$. Consider now the point
$$m:={a+b\over2}\in{\mathbb R}$$
and draw conclusions.

Comment: Why would I have (a+b)/2?