# Proof question: Show that if M is a point set, then there cannot be both a right most point of M and a first point to the right of M.

Tags: analysis

This is my proof so far,

Assume there is a right most point of M.
So a is an element of M for some point a,
Also assume there is a first point b to the right of M,
so b is an element of M for some point b.
Then a

I do not feel 100% confident that this would be correct. Are there any corrections or something I should change to make more sense for this proof?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you thinking of Real Numbers?  Integers?  Something else?

Comment: Also your proof appears to trail of as "Then a..."

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421660/show-that-if-m-subset-mathbb-r-then-there-cannot-be-both-a-right-most-point/2421742#2421742